# How to send data to AWS S3 from Kafka using Kakfa Connect without Confluent?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a local instance of Apache Kafka 2.0.0 , it running very well. In my test I produce and consume data from twitter and put them in a specific topic **twitter_tweets** and everything is OK. But now I want to consume the topic **twitter_tweets** with Kafka Connect using de connector [Kafka Connect S3](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3) and obviusly store the data in AWS S3 without using Confluent-CLI.

Can I do this without Confluent? Anyone have an example or something to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without Confluent

S3 Sink is open source; so is Apache Kafka Connect.

Connect framework is not specific to Confluent

You may use Kafka Connect Docker image, for example, or you may use `confluent-hub` to install S3 Connect on your own Kafka Connect installation.

Comment: the [Kafka Connect S3](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3) has a **Confluent Community License**. I run a test using only apache kafka without confluent and working for me, thanks a lot. But my question now is can I use the connector in my multicluster installation free?

Comment: Did you read the license? Where does it say that it is not free and source-available? The only limitation is that you cannot package and sell it as a competing product